# A Korean (Language) Dictionary

Tags: python, json

> **Function** : User enters a word in korean and the program translates (defines) it in english.
>
> What improvements can I make?
>
> **Extra** : What other challenges would you recommend that incorporates both JSON and python?

**KoreanDictionary.py**

```
import json
from difflib import get_close_matches

korean_data = json.load(open("korean_vocabulary.json"))

def my_translator(word):
    if word in korean_data.keys():
        return korean_data[word]
    elif len(get_close_matches(word,korean_data.keys(),n=1,cutoff=.69)) > 0:
        word = get_close_matches(word,korean_data.keys(),n=1,cutoff=.69)[0]
        return korean_data[word]
    else:
        return "Word does not exist."



if __name__ == '__main__':

    user_input = input("Define:")
    definition = str(my_translator(user_input)).replace('[','').replace(']','').replace("'",'')
    print(user_input + ": " + definition)
```

**korean_vocabulary.json**

```
{"안녕하세요": ["hello"],"죽어버려": ["GO DIE"],"상황": ["situation"],"어려워": ["hard; difficult"],
    "모르겠다": ["I don't know."],"조건": ["condition"],"정규직 직업": ["full-time job"],
    "탈락": ["eliminate; out"], "눈치": ["quick to catch; tactfulness"],"슬픈": ["sad"],
    "복잡한": ["complicated"],"완전": ["completely"],"반대": ["opposite"],"대박": ["jackpot; awesome"],
    "어꺠": ["shoulders"],"얼굴": ["face"]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if word in korean_data.keys():
    return korean_data[word]
```

This is better written as:

```
trans = korean_data.get(word)
if trans:
    return trans
```

This:

```
elif len(get_close_matches(word,korean_data.keys(),n=1,cutoff=.69)) > 0:
    word = get_close_matches(word,korean_data.keys(),n=1,cutoff=.69)[0]
    return korean_data[word]
```

calls for a few changes. Firstly, you don't need an `elif`, simply an `if` - because the previous block returned. Also, you should avoid re-issuing that entire `get_close_matches` call, and instead write a temporary variable:

```
words = get_close_matches(word,korean_data.keys(),n=1,cutoff=.69)
if words:
    return korean_data[words[0]]
```

This:

```
return "Word does not exist."
```

is not really good practice. It's "in-band error information", i.e. you're mixing valid data with an error message. Instead, you should be `raise`-ing an exception, catching it in your calling code, and outputting an error message there.

> What other challenges would you recommend that incorporates both JSON and python?

Download or scrape a real Korean-English dictionary dataset, either incorporating it into your application or setting up a REST client to contact a translation server somewhere. If local, save it as a format more efficient than JSON - perhaps compressed pickle, or SQLite. There are many ways to store a local database, and each has its advantages and disadvantages, but that's a topic for another question.

Comment: I would never recommend to use pickle, especially to someone not so experienced with it, it makes code vulnerable & dictionary file hardly manageable, can't see any pros in doing that, maybe using some sort of database (SQLite for beginning) can be a better idea

Comment: @AzatIbrakov It's only one of many alternatives, and it is appropriate for some cases (otherwise, why would it be included in Python?)

Comment: it is used internally, mainly in `multiprocessing` stdlib module, even [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) warns us that `pickle` is not secure

Comment: It's not secure against *maliciously constructed data*. In this use case (a translation dictionary), the data are not being supplied by the user, so the risk is lower.

Comment: why to use insecure, Python-specific, hardly-manageable solution, when there are tons of alternatives that better suite for purposes of persistence?

Comment: So like this: "raise Exception("Word does not exist.")" ???

Comment: An example why in-band error information is bad: https://boingboing.net/2008/07/15/chinese-restaurant-c.html

Comment: @austingae More or less. You'd probably want to use something more specific than `Exception` - perhaps `ValueError`.

Comment: I see. Better to be specific than to be vague ofc. Thanks.